# can not assign to Function without type parameters

Tags: java, generics

I do not understand why assignment to function without type parameters produces compilation error:

```
Function f1 = (Integer x) -> x;
```

I do not understand why because I can do it in following manner:

```
Function f2 = (Function<Integer, Integer>)((Integer x) -> x);
```

f1 and f2 has same types but I can do second assignment but not first.

I also can not do following assignment

```
Function<Object, Object> f3 = (Integer x) -> x;
```

but can do this one:

```
Function<Integer, Object> f4 = (Integer x) -> x;
```

Please explain why f2, f4 are valid while f1 and f3 are not.

Comment: Declare it as the correct type, `Function<Integer, Integer>`

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings, and address them properly.

Answer (score 1):

`f1` is invalid because `f1` uses raw types, and the type inference algorithm probably doesn't bother trying to handle it, because raw types are a legacy feature to interact with pre-Java 5 code; if you're using lambdas, you're not using pre-Java 5 code (here).

`f2` is valid because you're doing the work the type inference algorithm doesn't.

`f3` is invalid because `Integer` is not `Object`. You're saying "you can pass an `Object` to `f3`; but the lambda needs whatever you pass it to be an `Integer`.

`f4` is valid because the types are consistent.

Comment: Don't you think ``Object`` is not ``Integer`` instead of `Integer` is not `Object`?

Comment: Actually, for `f1` it seems the target type is the erased form of `Function::apply`, so you'd need: `Function f1 = (Object x) -> x;`

Comment: In f4 you claim that integer is consistent with object but in f3 you claims it's not.

Comment: @Trismegistos in `f4`, `Integer` (the first type parameter of the `Function`) is consistent with the parameter type of the lambda, `Integer`. In `f3`, `Object`, the first type parameter of the `Function` is inconsistent with the parameter type of the lambda, `Integer`.